# Loading image to another View Controller

Tags: ios, image

I have a drawing app with begins with choosing a category. Every category has his own drawing template. How do I get the secondViewController, to load the correct template? The category is chosen true a button from the firstViewController.

I have managed to give each segue a own identifier. And then what?
I only find examples of ways to parse data or images. But I don't want it to parse. I want it to load the image only on the secondViewController.

SecondViewController.h File

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *theCatImage;
```

SecondViewController.m File

```
@interface secondViewController()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;

@end
```

@implementation secondViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.image.image = self.theCatImage;

}
```

ViewController.h File

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "cat01ViewController.h"

@interface ikzieikzieAppViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *newImage;

@end
```

ViewController.m File

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"vervoer"]) {
    cat01ViewController *secondView = (cat01ViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    // dont know what to send here... i tried to hide and show a image like this;
    secondView.theCatImage = self.newImage;
}

}
```

**EDIT**
Above code doesn't work, ALSO i don't want to send a image from one to another viewcontroller. 
**This is what i want;**
On the firstViewController, a user can choose from four different categories. Each categorie will show his own drawing template and also, gives his own ID when the drawing is send to a parse database at the end. 
So, what is the best way to set this up?

*****SOLUTION*****

**Eventually, this is the way i solved it.**

ViewController

```
 -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"vervoer"]) {

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"vervoer.png"];
    cat01ViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    vc.showImage = image;
}

else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"huis"]) {

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"huis.png"];
    cat01ViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    vc.showImage = image;
}

else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mode"]) {

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"vinkje.png"];
    cat01ViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    vc.showImage = image;
}

else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"eten"]) {

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bord.png"];
    cat01ViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    vc.showImage = image;
}

}
```

SecondViewController

```
@synthesize catImage, showImage;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

   [catImage setImage:showImage];

   [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: Paste some code with what you've tried so far

Comment: i edited above with the code

Comment: i put in all the relevant code i have for now. 
This way it must send the picture from the 1st view, to the second. But it doesn't work AND i don't want the picture send from the 1st view, but only appear on the second view when a button on first view is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to add a property on `SecondViewController`:

```
@property (nonatomic) int category;
```

Then inside `FirstViewController`

Add property

```
@property (nonatomic) int chosenCategory;
```

Set this to the category that the user selected.

Then inside your seque code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
  cat01ViewController *secondView = (cat01ViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
  [secondView setCategory:self.chosenCategory];
}
```

This will tell the VC which image it will need to draw. Then you call your parse library method to retrieve the image based on the ID (Category) chosen inside the `viewDidLoad` method in `SecondViewController`:

`SecondViewController`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.image.image = [ParseLibrary getImageForCategory:self.chosenCategory];

}
```